# Rspec - devise - rails: User session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I need to test the content of a view which has a devise authentication filter `before_filter :authenticate_user!`

When i run the test, the app doesn't have a logged user and redirects to /users/sign_in. Then the test searches the content on this view.

How can i simulate the user session or skip this filter to make the test, **without** using FactoryGirl ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at ControllerMacros

```
module ControllerMacros
   def login_user
    before(:each) do
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      @current_user = user
      sign_in user
    end
  end
end
```

spec/spec_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  ....
  config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :controller
end
```

spec/controllers/some_controller_spec.rb

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../spec_helper'

describe SomeController, "index" do
    context "for authenticated users" do
        login_user
        ...
    end
end
```

It is pretty useful when you have controller logic based on different user roles.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't want to use FactoryGirl, but finally it was the best way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your spec:

`controller.class.skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!`

An alternative(probably better) approach is to check out the devise docs to see their recommended testing pattern.